# Ypipes and wookmark jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, image-resizing, yahoo-pipes

I am trying to combine yahoo pipes with wookmark jquery.  The issue I am having is some of the images are not resizing correctly.  I have it up at http://justawebbie.com/wookmark-ypipe/.  The page is real clean just has the code for the wookmark and pipes on it.

Would someone please help me figure out what I have done wrong in the combining of these to scripts?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add ".tiles li img { width: 200px !important; height: auto; }" to your CSS, that should do it.